# Dynamically assign class object to function

Tags: python, dataframe, class, oop

following @MisterMiyagi comment(Thanks!),

I rephrase my unclear previous question with (hopefully) better/shorter example.

In main script ,
I initialize obj with Class Exmaple .
I pass test as **kwargs to class ,
Next, I call the function with intention to assign self.test using curr_test

Expected:
self.test will print "test"
actual:
it didn't work, result holds "test" but it didn't assign any change to self.test.

main:

```
from my_class import example

obj = example(test = "")

obj._Test(obj.test)

print(len(obj.test))


# prints "0" expected "test"
```

class:

```
class example:
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        
    def _Test(self, curr_test = ''  ):
        curr_test = 'test'
        print("curr_test :",curr_test ,"class test:",self.test)
```

Comment: Please clarify what exactly does not work, and how – does it throw an error? If so, which? Note that your code is incomplete – please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - I actually did mention what does work, maybe i wasn't clear , hopefully now it's better .

Comment: Just to be clear: By passing ``obj.df_va1`` as ``df_result``, you expect ``df_result = ...`` to actually assign to ``obj.df_va1``? Like an in-out parameter?

Comment: You cannot return function results by way of an argument the way you are doing here.  Your obj.df_va1 in the outer scope will be unchanged.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - yes , by passing obj.df_va1 to the function as df_result i expect obj.df_va1 be updated with the values of cluster.query(statment).
The reason behind that is to keep reuse this function and dynamically assign class objects

Comment: Is there any reason why you do not just remove ``df_result `` but instead ``return cluster.query(statment)`` and do ``obj.df_va1= obj._CountOnBucket(obj.bucket_1,obj.cluster_1)``?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - I rephrase the question , with shorter code as an example,Sorry for  confusion .

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - i implement the changes as you suggest and it's working (thanks), I still wonder if there's an option to have the internal variable inside the function as reference to self.test (see example)

Comment: Your new edit confuses the issue even more than the original.  For one thing, your new main example doesn't call the renamed function in your class.  And it doesn't very often make sense to call an object's member functions passing in arguments that are already attributes of that object.

Comment: @RufusVS, thanks for the comment , i fixed the call from main.